# Require UAC password different from the user password

Tags: windows-8, passwords, uac

Is there is a way to make UAC prompt for a password that is not the password of any of the users on the PC? Is there a way to set a UAC password so that not even any of the administrators could successfully trespass UAC?

The background is that I have a computer whose default (and only) user is the administrator and I want so set it up so that for any major change to the PC, a password is required without adding a new accout.

Comment: Remove their admin privileges, make them a standard user.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am sorry I forgot to add a crucial information. (See the last sentence)

Comment: You already have 'the other account', it's called Administrator.

Comment: The simplest solution stop using the default Administrator account to log into the computer.  I am not sure what you mean by "successfully trespass UAC" please explain in detail what you mean.  The default `Administrator` account has some not so subtle differences between a user profile placed in the Administrator user group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done. UAC only accepts credentials of user accounts that are valid on the computer, whether they be local or domain accounts.

In order to prompt for a password that is different from the one used by your logon account, you **must** create/use another account.

Comment: Is it possible to use the internal "hidden" admin account to prompt for a password, while the other users are no longer grouped as admins?

Comment: Yes, so long as that account is not disabled. Whatever you decide to do, you don't want to end up with a scenario where you can no longer *logon* with an Administrator account.

Comment: (I've actually had that one before... ) // I just found this one that might be interesting http://superuser.com/questions/182375/always-display-the-last-default-user-windows-7-welcome-screen/182382#182382 Using this, I can "hide" the other accounts.

Comment: @user1574054 Excellent find. Yes, this would be a good way to go about it.