# Hide Administrator account from Windows login screen

Tags: windows-10

I have enabled the Administrator account so that I can use it with `runas` in command prompt, but now the account is displayed also on the login screen.

Is there a way to hide the Administrator account from the login screen without disabling/deleting it?

[image: administrator account on login screen]

Comment: While the linked answer is indeed the same as this one, it does not pop up in google or SO search when using the correct full account name "**Administrator**". This was the reason why I created this QA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `regedit` and create **new KEY** `SpecialAccounts\UserList` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WIndows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` by right-clicking the `Winlogon` folder in the left panel.

In this new subkey (UserList) right-click to create a **DWORD** value with name of the account you want to hide.

[image: regedit]

To show the account again, remove the DWORD, or alternatively you can set a value of the DWORD to

- `0` *(default when created)* to hide
- `1` to show the account again

You can immediately test that it works by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
[image: empty login screen]

*PS: This answer really is just a copypasta from [this burried question at answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security-winpc/hide-admin-account-from-windows-10-login-screen/df125c70-a49b-4737-bcc0-3da82512a2f3) enhanced with my own screenshots to help basic users.*

You can read more related information in these SO QAs
[How to hide admin account and only show main user at logon screen in Windows?](https://superuser.com/a/278221/99602)
[Hide account from login screen but can be used in UAC](https://superuser.com/questions/66400/hide-account-from-login-screen-but-can-be-used-in-uac)

Comment: It's worth noting that the data of the registry value must be `0` to have the intended effect. That's implicit given you have the user create the new value, but the answer would be more useful if this is stated explicitly.

Comment: unable to run any file with admin rights now.
+ Windows is corrupted now.
Do NOT try this solution for God's Sake.